# Effect of increasing number of instructions on size of MIPS fields

Tags: mips

If the 32-bit MIPS architecture had four times as many instructions, how would this affect the size of each of the bit fields in the R-type instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of instructions is limited either by the number of distinct instructions designed by the ISA architect, or the size of the opcode field. So, if we assume we've maxed-out the number of available opcodes and we keep the instruction size the same, we need to find two bits in order to increase the size of the opcode field to give us 4x the number of possible opcodes.

So, the total size of other bit fields has to decrease by 2 collectively.

Note that this is an answer to the general question you are pointing at, not the specific case of MIPS-32

Comment: Would we need to increase the size of the funct field as well? Some instructions such as add, uses both the opcode and funct feilds.

Comment: I think it would depend on the type of instructions you are adding